# Reading a file containing a stream of JSON documents

Tags: python, json

I have an input file with a JSON document per line. I'm trying to read it as follows:

```
import json
auth = []
with open("test.json",'rb') as authfile:
    infile=authfile.readlines()
    for line in infile:  
        auth_record = json.load(line)
        auth.append(auth_record)
```

And I got the below error. What went wrong?

```
auth_record = json.load(line)
  File "/opt/anaconda/anaconda/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 286, in load
    return loads(fp.read(),
 AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'read'
```

Comment: Have you looked at the contents of realtime.json to see if it is valid JSON?  The error message points out specifically where in the file it had trouble.

Comment: Check out [jsonlint.com](http://jsonlint.com/). Paste in your JSON file and see if it's valid.

Comment: The question is incomplete without enough information to reproduce the problem -- in this case, that means a JSON file cut down to contain minimum necessary contents that repro the bug.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. I double check the file, it's not a json file, instead it's a file with line-delimited json object.

Answer (score 0):

If you're parsing a string (as what you get in `for line in file`), use `json.loads()`, not `json.load()` [which expects a file-like object, and is thus complaining when you pass it a string instead].

Thus something like:

```
for line in infile:
    auth.append(json.loads(line))
```

Answer (score -3):

Ussualy this error could be due an unicode encoding,

Try to put this directive in the first line of your code file

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

Otherwise try to open the file, edit the line with troublemaker char and add the error in the question to help you better

Comment: No. This has nothing to do with encoding, and even if it did putting that declaration would not help in any way at all.

Comment: ...particularly, has nothing to do with the *source file*'s encoding, as it's occurring when parsing content which is not itself Python source.